# GAE and Google API Client PHP crashes CGI/FastCGI

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-analytics, cgi, google-analytics-api

When trying to run the [HelloAnalytics.php](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) file from the official Google Documentation using the Google App Engine SDK CGI/FastCGI crashes. When trying to deploy the same example the same happens again.

This issue has been [reported on github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/640) but I'm in need of an workaround. Anyone have a known solution?

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini in the root of your project, you can enable curl by adding this line to your php.ini. I had a similar sounding problem using gitkit with appengine and this solved the issue.

extension = "php_curl.dll"